# Getting illegal character error while using closure-compiler.jar using ANT for r.js optimization

Tags: java, javascript, ant, r.js

I am using closure compiler jar for minification in r.js optimization in windows environment.

While running this task using ANT exec, getting **illegal character** error but while running same task using **.bat** file it working fine.

**ANT exec task**

```
<target name="do-optimization" description="It will do optimization using r.js.">
    <exec dir="." executable="java" failonerror="true">
        <arg value="-jar" />
        <arg path="${src.dir}/r-js/lib/rhino/js.jar" />
        <arg path="${src.dir}/r-js/lib/closure/compiler.jar" />
        <arg path="${src.dir}/r-js/dist/r.js" />
        <arg value="-o"/>
        <arg path="${src.dir}/r-js/build.js" />
    </exec>
</target>
```

**console output**

```
do-optimization:
 [exec] js: "C:\workspace\test\ui\r-js\lib\closure\compiler.jar", line 2: illegal character
 [exec] js:   ╝MOC                   ♦ META-INF/■╩  PK♥♦
 [exec] js: ^
 [exec] js: "C:\workspace\test\ui\r-js\lib\closure\compiler.jar", line 1: Compilation produced 1 syntax errors.
 [exec]

 BUILD FAILED
```

**optimize.bat**

```
java -classpath "r-js\lib\rhino\js.jar";"r-js\lib\closure\compiler.jar" org.mozilla.javascript.tools.shell.Main r-js/dist/r.js -o build.js
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't seem that the Ant script is calling `java` the same way as the batch file. The `exec` task is calling the following command:

```
java -jar ${src.dir}/r-js/lib/rhino/js.jar ${src.dir}/r-js/lib/closure/compiler.jar ${src.dir}/r-js/dist/r.js -o ${src.dir}/r-js/build.js
```

which is clearly different than the one in the .bat file, i.e. the jars are not being added to the classpath properly.

In Ant, you can simply use the [`java`](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/java.html) task to run a Java class. Try using the following:

```
<java classname="org.mozilla.javascript.tools.shell.Main" failonerror="true">
    <arg path="${src.dir}/r-js/dist/r.js" />
    <arg value="-o"/>
    <arg path="${src.dir}/r-js/build.js" />
    <classpath>
        <pathelement location="${src.dir}/r-js/lib/rhino/js.jar" />
        <pathelement location="${src.dir}/r-js/lib/closure/compiler.jar" />
    </classpath>
</java>
```